# Stop the ajax request on window.history.pushState using $routeProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, routes

I'm using `$routeProvider` with `html5Mode` in my application.

My problem is that if I use this option to change my URL without reloading the site `window.history.pushState('page2', 'Title', '/page2.php');`

The angular does not reload **BUT** the `$routeProvider` loads the new url.

As you can see in the image:
[image]

**I wonder** how I can change the url without the angular do a request of that url.

I know there functions to prevent reload the page but none avoid the request of the new url.

**My problem is that I can stop the page reload, but can not stop the ajax request.**

Answer (score 0):

I can't give you details, because I don't know angular :) but in theory you could update the router (routeProvider) to have a global action for /* for example and detect the pushState event there. 
You can do that by setting a flag on pushState or by looking to the onpopstate "event".

Comment: I tried something like that but unfortunately without success. Thank you anyways.